# Best, profitable bitcoin mining complete rig under 1000 dollars

Tags: motherboard

I am new to bitcoin mining and im looking for a complete rig (either ASIC or GPU) under 1000 dollars that would mine any crypto currency. Something that would be profitable and fast.

Electricity price is 0.045 dollars.

Comment: Graphics cards and bitcoin mining does not work together very well. And about the profitability, that also depends on your electricity price

Comment: Are you looking for an ASIC setup? If you're hoping to do it on a regular computer, you won't make a penny a month. Also, forget silent. You have to keep an ASIC cool. Never buy a second hand one, because you don't know how well it's been kept & used. People run these things into the ground, then try to dob them off to newbies who don't know any better… & bear in mind that unless you're going to be finding a co-operative, your one miner is going to be up against the big boys. *There's a lot of reading you need to do.*

Comment: @Tetsujin can you recommend something

Comment: Don't bother with GPU rigs. Look for ASIC. Bitmain would be about your entry level.

Comment: That thing is NOT worth it. You will need to add your own GPU's to that and won't mine Bitcoin very fast. About Eutherium (which it is ment to mine), it will move to Proof of Stake (probably sooner than later) and your mining rig will be useless